# Passing a String into macro using the Macro window in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Is possible to pass a string into a macro using the macro toolbar/window in outlook.

For example i have a macro like below

```
Sub messagebox(msgtxt As String)

 MsgBox (msgtxt)

End Sub
```

I would like to pass a string "test" from outlook macro window (like picture below).

[image]

Comment: Why not use `Inputbox` to enter the custom string ?

Comment: Im using an RPA software that starts the macro was hoping i could pass the variable through here.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. RPA can enter the variable in an InputBox as well, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could create a sub like this

```
Sub MessageBox_Test ()
  MessBox "test"
End Sub
```

and then also create another sub like this

```
Sub MessBox (sMessage As String)
  MsgBox sMessage
End Sub
```

Which would accomplish the same thing if you call MessageBox_Test from the button.

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this ?**

```
Sub messagebox()

    Dim msgtxt As String
    msgtxt = InputBox("Type Your Msg")

    MsgBox (msgtxt)

End Sub
```